# Newbie - need script to remove duplicates based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm super new to Google Sheets - as I mostly use Excel and Smartsheet. I was trying to accomplish this by just recording a macro, so this is VERY messy.

I have a doc that we're uploading data into on a regular basis, and need to be able to remove duplicated items.

The items that have already been sorted will have a category applied, so my thought was that we could remove items duplicated in column 'H' (opp id) and then with a blank cell in Column 'B' (Category)

The way I was doing it at first was to record the macro with me manually doing the conditional formatting to highlight duplicates on column H, and then pulled a script from here to delete rows that were blank in column B. However, the script removes ALL items that are blank in column B and not just the items I had filtered based on the conditional formatting.

I know this is because the script is pulling the whole sheet, but I just can't figure out how to fix it.

```
    function DeleteDuplicates() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J9').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Report'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('H:H').activate();
  var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(0, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('H1:H981')])
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=countif(H:H,H1)>1')
  .setBackground('#FF00FF')
  .setFontColor('#000000')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  spreadsheet.getRange('J15').activate();
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D15').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Report'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:AC112').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:AC112').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(8, criteria);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[1] == '') {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;}
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(8);
  spreadsheet.getRange('J13').activate();
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: You have been viewed 20 times and my guess is that everyone has looked at your code and quickly come to the conclusion that you learned how to code by building macros.  Personally, I hate to view code written in this way and I would recommend that you rewrite your code without the use of methods like activate() and setActiveSheet() and getActiveSheet()

Answer (score 1):

> so my thought was that we could remove items duplicated in column 'H'
> (opp id) and then with a blank cell in Column 'B' (Category)

Essentially, you are looking to **remove all rows with duplicate Column H values AND with blank cells in Column B**?

If that's the case,

**Try:**

```
function myFunction() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`Report`)
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  const uniqueItems = [... new Set(data.map(i => i[7]))]

  const updatedData = []
  for (let item of uniqueItems) {
    const itemData = data.filter(i => i[7] === item)
    if (itemData.length > 1) {
      itemData.filter(i => i[1] !== ``)
              .forEach(i => updatedData.push(i))
    } else { updatedData.push(...itemData) }
  }

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, updatedData.length, updatedData[0].length).setValues(updatedData)

}
```

**Commented:**

```
function myFunction() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`Report`)
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  // Get all unique items in the sheet.
  const uniqueItems = [... new Set(data.map(i => i[7]))]

  const updatedData = []
  // For each unique item..
  for (let item of uniqueItems) {
    // Get all rows containing the item.
    const itemData = data.filter(i => i[7] === item)
    // If there's more than one row..
    if (itemData.length > 1) {
      // Remove all rows with blank cells in Column B...
      itemData.filter(i => i[1] !== ``)
              // ... and add to our updatedData.
              .forEach(i => updatedData.push(i))
    // If there's only one row for this item, add to updatedData
    } else { updatedData.push(...itemData) }
  }

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, updatedData.length, updatedData[0].length).setValues(updatedData)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Description**

Based on your original script it seems your programming experience is limited.  Although NEWAZA's methods may work I propose a simpilier script that may be easier for you to follow.  Much of original script is from moving the cursor around while recording a macro and is redundant.  Instead I propose a simple macro that should be easy for you to follow.

I'm assuming new data is added and so I first perform a sort of column H and B.  Then I loop through backwards to find duplicates and blank cells and delete rows that match the criteria.  I loop backwards so I don't have to keep track of row number as rows are deleted.  I'm also assuming rows to be deleted are not contiguous which may result in a slight performance hit.

**Script**

```
function deleteDuplicates() {
  try {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Report');
    let range = sheet.getDataRange();
    range.sort([{column: 8, ascending: true},{column: 2, ascending: false}]);
    let values = range.getValues();
    // assuming the conditional format rule has already been applied to this sheet
    for( let i=values.length; i>2; i-- ) {
      let j = i-1;
      let k = j-1;
      if( ( values[j][7] === values[k][7] ) && ( values[j][1] === "" ) ) {
        sheet.deleteRow(i);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Range.sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))